# How do you configure JHipster-JDL to not create primary keys automatically?

Tags: jhipster

That is, considering I have JHipster-JDL entities that just "extends" others in Java code therefore they don't need any Primary Key, how can I configure JHipster to not create any PK for the entities I want to?

Answer (score 1):

You can't because JDL does not support entity inheritance nor defining your own PK.

Comment: Thanks, @Gaël Marziou. So I'll only be able to do this work mannualy